# Unable to gain access to Name for Files within a Site Share Point

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have method where I am adding new files to a Site. I am trying to implement a method where I can delete a file from a Site. Currently the method is deleting the files from oldest to newest. Where I would like to have access to `Name` or `DisplayName` to perform a `if` check. When I try to access `listitem.DisplayName` I am met with en error of:

*"The property or field 'DisplayName' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."*

If someone can please help me understand how to allow `listitem.DisplayName` to be accessible I would greatly appreciate it!

---

**DeleteAFile()**

```
 public static void DeleteAFile(string sFileName, string sFldrLoc)
    {

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

        List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(sFldrLoc);


        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

        ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(query);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



        foreach (ListItem listitem in listItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listitem.DisplayName); // Line that is throwing error

           // listitem.DeleteObject();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your invocation of `clientContext.Load` to indicate which properties to retrieve for each list item.

```cs
clientContext.Load(listItems, 
    items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
    item => item.DisplayName));
```

For reference, see [How to retrieve list items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539350(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection5).

Comment: I am unaware of how to use you're code snippet. I have tried to plug it in but I am generating errors. I have updated the method to reflect the changes.

Comment: I was getting errors since my method was not updated. I will update the code, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

Thank you to *Thriggle* for the link which helped me solved this. Updated code below:

**DeleteAFile()**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Will list out all the items within a Site, conduct a search and delete the item when found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sFileName"></param>
    /// <param name="sFldrLoc"></param>
    public static void DeleteAFile(string sFileName, string sFldrLoc)
    {

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);

        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection collList = web.Lists;

        List oList = collList.GetByTitle(sFldrLoc);

        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();

        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Leq>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>100</Value>" +
            "</Leq></Where></Query><RowLimit>50</RowLimit></View>";

        ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(query);

        clientContext.Load(collListItem,
            items => items.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(
                item => item.DisplayName));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


        foreach (ListItem listitem in collListItem)
        {
            if (listitem.DisplayName.Equals(sFileName))
            {
                listitem.DeleteObject();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("{0}, has been deleted sucessfully!", listitem.DisplayName);
            }

        }
    }
```